# How to prevent adding typed keys into controlled TextInput in React-Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on money entering the Input field and I need to write my own logic to enter numbers. That part is working but on an Android emulator, the typed number appears before the controlled component takes effect. In the Expo playground, it works fine but on Android emulator the text jumps:

this simplified code that shows the issue:

```
const ControlledComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('0.00');
  const cursor = 1;
  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={ref}
      autoFocus
      onKeyPress={() => { /* empty */ }}
      selection={{start: cursor, end: cursor}}
      value={state}
      keyboardType="numeric"
    />
  );
};
```

If you have a component like this the input accepts a new numeric value even though it's controlled and should not update. In the browser, this will freeze the input. But on React-Native the text jumps, it enters the character for a split second, and then the state return to the original value.

[image: Andorid emulator with moneyInput]

I've tried `event.preventDefault()` and empty onChange event but they don't work, I keep getting default input.

The question can you do something for the text to not jump and display what is in the state?

Comment: This is a bug in React-Native, check this issue on GitHub: [Can't prevent default input in TextInput in controlled component](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38155)

Comment: If you want to know how I solve it, I've added a fake keyboard written in React-Native.